# r - reinsertion of intersection points into initial dataset after sf::st_intersection

Tags: r, point, intersection, sf

I have one dataset with `POINTS` called `pts1`. I'm connecting them into a`LINESTRING` and I'm calculating intersection points of that `LINESTRING` with multiple `LINESRINGs` from another dataset. The main goal is when the intersection points are calculated I want them to be reinserted into the `pts1` dataset in their corresponding place. Maybe there is a function in `sf` I don't know about or maybe this can be done with several conditions ?

Simplified example below:

```
# initial dataset
pts1 <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1), lon = c(2,4,5,7,8), lat = c(1,4,3,2,5)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), dim = "XY") %>% st_set_crs(4326)

# make linestring
lns1 <- pts1 %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(geometry = st_union(geometry), do_union = FALSE) %>% st_cast("LINESTRING")

# second dataset with multiple linestrings
lns2 <- data.frame(mark = c(1,1,2,2), lon = c(3,3,6.5,6.5), lat = c(1,4,1,4)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), dim = "XY") %>% st_set_crs(4326) %>%
  group_by(mark) %>% summarise(geometry = st_union(geometry), do_union = FALSE) %>% st_cast("LINESTRING")

# intersection points
inters <- st_intersection(lns1, lns2)

# desired output: the intersection points have been reinserted in the first dataset pts1 between the original two points where the lines intersected
desired_df <- data.frame(id = c(1,NA,1,1,NA,1,1), 
               lon = c(2,3,4,5,6.5,7,8), 
               lat = c(1,2.5,4,3,2.25,2,5),
               mark = c(NA,1,NA,NA,2,NA,NA)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), dim = "XY") %>% st_set_crs(4326)
```

[image: Current and desired outcome]

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Edzer Pebesma the following can be used to answer the question:

```
library(lwgeom) 
library(sf)
st_split(st_linestring(rbind(c(0,0), c(1,1))), st_linestring(rbind(c(0,1), c(1,0)))) %>%
  st_collection_extract("LINESTRING") %>% 
  st_combine() %>% 
  st_line_merge()
```

Further on any ideas on how to keep the attributes of the geometries are welcome

Answer (score 1):

You might use `st_node` to ensure the intersection points are present, and then find the intersection of that with the first object. You'll have to remove the POINT geometries ... and I haven't checked this in more complex situations.

```
g1 <- st_geometry(lns1)
g2 <- st_geometry(lns2)
d <- st_sf(geometry = c(g1, g2), dataset = rep(c("a", "b"), c(length(g1), length(g2))))

st_intersection(st_node(d), lns1)
```

Comment: this answer did not provide the desired sf dataframe. Instead the output was a simple feature collection. The desired output would be sf dataframe in which the intersection points are inserted, ordered according to where the intersection happenned

Comment: yes, sorry - I realized later this wasn't right - it must get normalized by the geom engine - still have an idea, and I think I've seen it done

Comment: First of all thank you for trying. It would be very useful to me personally if there could be a solution to this. It is a major problem on a project I'm working on

Comment: It's a majorly general useful thing to do ;) We still need the complete union version, but that's probably possible more simply by node and combine plus intersect, this is helpful discussion

Comment: I agree 100%. The only down side with this solution is that the attributes of the geometries are lost which is really important. On the other hand `sf::st_intersection` gives the information of which `linestring` got intersected with which `linestring`. My background is not in GIS nor in R which is my excuse of not being able to think of a solution. If we can fix that I believe it can be very useful

Comment: Yeah, simple features is really not suited to working with piecewise structures. It'll be possible but super-specific and weird. I'm interested in this but I likely won't have an answer soon